# Copy a row from a table to another table in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is my first time working with Access so I am kind of confused now. Here is my code and I don't know which part is wrong. There isn't error but there isn't anything happening after I click the button. Thanks! Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Amity")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Opportunity")
With rs2
.AddNew
.Fields("Donor_Code") = rs!Donor_Code
.Update
.Close
End With
rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried these but still nothing change and no error: Private Sub Command12_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Amity")
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Opportunity")
While Not rs.EOF
rs2.AddNew
rs2![Donor_Code] = rs![Donor_Code]
rs2.Update
rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs2.Close
rs.Close

End Sub

Comment: Are you sure this code was run? Try to set break point or check if button Command12 has event .onClick at its properties sheet. And if it has, it leads to your Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a Do loop:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

  Dim db As Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = CurrentDb()    
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Amity")
  Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("Opportunity")

  Do While (Not rs.EOF)
    rs2.AddNew
    rs2.Fields("Donor_Code").Value = rs!Donor_Code.Value
    rs2.Update
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
'
  rs2.Close
  Set rs2 = Nothing
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
'
End Sub
```